# Using getElementsByTagName to find all hrefs in a variable

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

In a variable I'm holding HTML source code, which I obtained from DB. I'd like to search this content through for all the "a href" attributes and list them in a table.

Now I've found here how to search it in a DOM (like below), but how to use it to search within a variable?

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a").getElementsByAttribute("href");
```

Got this currently, which is searching by RegEx, but it doesn't work very well:

```
matches_temp = result_content.match(/\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’&quote]))/ig);
```

In result_content I'm holding that HTML Source.

Comment: Not all A elements have a href attribute. Have you considered using a [*DOMparser*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and using the [*links*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/links) property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a nodelist that does not have a method called `getElementsByAttribute` but ONLY if you have DOM access

**Without DOM** (for example node.js)

```js
const hrefRe = /href="(.*?)"/g;
const urlRe = /\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’&quote]))/ig;

 
const stringFromDB = `<a href="http://000">000</a>
Something something <a href="http://001">001</a> something`

stringFromDB.match(hrefRe).forEach(
 (href) => console.log(href.match(urlRe)[0] ) 
);

// oldschool: 
// stringFromDB.match(hrefRe).forEach(function(href) {  console.log(href.match(urlRe)[0] )      });
```

In this code I create a DOM snippet first 
Also I ONLY get anchors that have an href to begin with

**NOTE** the getAttribute so the browser does not try to interpret the URL

With the regex if you wanted to only match SPECIFIC types of href:

```js
const re = /\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’&quote]))/ig;

const stringFromDB = `<a href="http://000">000</a>
<a href="http://001">001</a>`

let doc = document.createElement("div");
doc.innerHTML = stringFromDB

doc.querySelectorAll("a[href]").forEach(
  (x) => console.log(x.getAttribute("href").match(re)[0])
);
```

Without the regex

```js
const stringFromDB = `<a href="http://000">000</a>
<a href="http://001">001</a>`

let doc = document.createElement("div");
doc.innerHTML = stringFromDB

doc.querySelectorAll("a[href]").forEach(
 (x) => console.log(x.getAttribute("href")) 
);
```

Comment: @RobG OP is not parsing HTML, he is matching HTML in an HREF! I am using the DOM to get the href

Comment: Ah.. I of course assume he creates a DOM snippet first

Comment: Sorry, but I'm struggling to understand how did you connect that RegEx I wanted to skip entirely into that matching?

Comment: I thought you wanted to only list the hrefs that matched your very long RegEx. If you do not need it, don't use it, just use `x.getAttribute("href")`

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan , but now I'm getting "document.createElement is not a function." error on compilation

Comment: "Compilation"? Are you running this in a browser or on node or something?

Comment: If on the server, you need https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom or similar

Comment: On a server. Is there any other way I could do this without using "querySelectorAll"

Comment: If there’s no DOM then you need your regex

Comment: How do I modify the regex so that before it matches anything it checks whether it starts with href=" (I can later substring that) [(/\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’&quote]))/ig);]

Comment: Have a look at the last example

Comment: Thanks. I struggle to comprehend that unusual (in my mind) forEach syntax. I got this working in a RegEx tester: href=\"\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’&quote])) but when compiled it doesn't like the " character

Comment: `stringFromDB.match(hrefRe).forEach(function(href)  { console.log(href.match(urlRe)[0] ) 
});`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't be using RegEx to parse HTML. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/10221765) explains why.

Secondly, you're using `getElementsByAttribute` incorrectly - it does exactly what it says and *gets elements by attributes*. You should just use `querySelectorAll` on all elements with a `href`, and then `map` out the `href`s:

```js
var hrefs = document.querySelectorAll("a[href*=http]");
var test = Array.prototype.slice.call(hrefs).map(e => e.href);
console.log(test);
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com">Example</a>
<a href="http://example1.com">Example 1</a>
<a href="http://example2.com">Example 2</a>
<a href="http://example3.com">Example 3</a>
```

Comment: `use querySelectorAll on all elements with a href, and then map out the hrefs:` is what I do in my answer

Comment: The OP mentioned *getElementsByTagName* as an example, they aren'tt using it, so *getElementsByAttribute* is a red herring. They're thinking of parsing HTML, but as you note, that's not a good idea. Better to use *innerHTML* or, if the source is not 100% trustworthy, a *DOMParser* and then use DOM methods to get the links.